# IIS possibly caching the status of the Active Directory server

Tags: iis, active-directory

We have a situation where if the Active Directory server has a temporary problem possibly a network/DNS glitch, then after it is fixed the web application running under IIS still receives this error:

"The server could not be contacted.   at
 System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(String serverName, ServerProperties& properties)"

This situation clears when IIS is reboot or we run iisreset.exe.

Could it be that IIS is caching the status of the downed directory server. In which case how can we avoid that?

Comment: Are you reusing the same `PrincipalContext` object when you retry? Or are you creating a new one each time?